# How can I convert a string to "gbk" encoding?

Tags: python, byte, encode, cjk

I'm trying to convert some Chinese words into bytes with Python. For example, I have this word: 自 and I tried to convert it by doing this:

`"自".encode()`

But I only get this:

`b'\xe8\x87\xaa'`

Looking on the web I think that it needs to be converted with "gbk" encoding but if I try to do it I only get:

`b'\xd7\xd4'`

What I need is it to be converted into this:

`\u81ea`

Here you can see a reference to the character I'm talking about: https://charbase.com/81EA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u81ea` is a unicode code point not gbk bytes.

You can convert to this with:

```
"自".encode("unicode_escape")
# b'\\u81ea'
```

`b'\xd7\xd4'` is the gbk encoding of that code point, `b'\xe8\x87\xaa'` is the utf-8 encoding of the same code point.